# Pass command line variable to Jinja macro

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am a running dbt with command line input:

```
dbt run --vars {my_key, my_date_variable}
```

I have a model:

```
SELECT 
   id,
   my_jinja_func(my_date_variable) AS x
FROM my_table
```

*error: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'AS'*

I cant seem to figure out how to pass the variable correctly to the jinja function.  Any help appreciated.

Many Thanks. M.

Comment: Have you read through [this documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/jinja-macros)? Jinja only processes content enclosed in appropriate template delimiters (typically `{{...}}`).

Comment: I updated to my_jinja_function(var('my_date_variable')), which worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I have encountered a secondary issue.

My date parameter eg. date_param = '2024-01-30'

```
{% macro my_jinja_function(date_param) %}
  {% set converted_date = modules.datetime.datetime.strptime(date_param, '%Y-%M-%D').DATE %}

{{ date_param }}

{% endmacro %}
```

My select statement column entry is return an integer

```
Select my_jinja_function(date_param) as x
```

returns '1993' as col x value.

Solution was '{{ date_param }}'  (quotes) to return date string for SQL.